# Changing the background image of a Activity which extends ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout

I followed the tutorial at: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-listview/ 
and was able to successfully run the application. It mainly uses a xml file called list_item.xml and its contents are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="24dp"
android:padding="6dp" />
```

And in a file called TutListActivity.java, this xml is loaded as:

```
public class TutListActivity extends ListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
            R.array.tut_titles, R.layout.list_item));
}}
```

AND THIS IS THE FIRST ACTIVITY WHICH GETS LOADED WHEN THE APPLICATION IS LAUNCHED FIRST. My requirement is TO CHANGE THE BACKGROUND VIEW OF THE COMPLETE SCREEN. When I tried android:background=@drawable/paperImage in the xml file list_item.xml, I was able to change the background image of each of the rows in the List and not the complete View. Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: where you r setting your contentview like setContentView(R.layout.some_name); anything like this ?

Comment: I was confused too at first, but in the tutorial link which I have posted in the begining of the Question, the author mentions : n TutListActivity.java, modify the onCreate() method to use the setListAdapter() method to load up the data. Unlike regular activities, a ListActivity does not need the use of setContentView() for cases where the entire activity is just a ListView.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just use the following lines written below with the id of your image after setListAdapter  i hope this is what you want

```
ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setCacheColorHint(0);
    lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myMainBackground);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 xml layouts you specify for the listview. 1 is for the activity and the other is for a row of the listview. You should set the background for layout used for the activity ie the layout you put in setContentView. Right now you are setting the background image to the row xml file.

Comment: Nope, Im making use of only one xml file which has a single textView element. And I am loading that from TutListActivity.java as mentioned in this tutorial : http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-listview/
I just wanted what Sam Janz has suggested above.